# Is there a way to log a per request unique id for nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

There appear to be a couple of third party modules for this

- https://github.com/newobj/nginx-x-rid-header
- https://github.com/hhru/nginx_requestid

However if possible I don't want to rebuild nginx, which I believe, is a requirement to use both of these modules. My initial try was to use `$msec` with `$pid` however that didn't work out (I had a process serve two requests at the same millisecond). I've read about `$connection` and it seems like that would work in conjunction with `$msec`. Will this work or is there a better way without using third party modules?

Answer (score 15):

Update for nginx version v1.11 (May 2016):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_id

You can use `$request_id`:

> unique request identifier generated from 16 random bytes, in
>   hexadecimal (1.11.0)

Comment: For old version (<= 1.2.7), you can use something like "$pid-$date_local" which should be unique enough for most usage.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `nginx-extras` and use embedded Perl or Lua.

`$ sudo apt-get install libossp-uuid-perl`

In your nginx configuration:

```
perl_require "Data/UUID.pm";
perl_set $request_uuid 'sub {

    my $ug = new Data::UUID;
   return $ug->create_str();
}';
```

And then for a given `location`:

```
proxy_set_header Request-Id $request_uuid
```

We're using [this in production](https://github.com/alphagov/pp-puppet/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=uuid) and are very happy with the better tracing that we have across our backend services.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use **nginx-extras** or **perl** in nginx.

Then you can set request variable using **perl_set**

```
perl_set $uuid 'sub {
  return join "", map{(a..z,A..Z,0..9)[rand 62]} 0..7;
}';
```

If you need more details:
http://yozik04.blogspot.com/2014/12/nginx-request-id-using-perl.html